# TASK ERROR: command 'systemctl start pve-container@102' failed: exit code 1

Tags: virtual-machines, proxmox

I executed this command `apt update && apt upgrade`. After that, all container start except the ftp container. Launch this error: `Job for pve-container@102.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status pve-container@102.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. TASK ERROR: command 'systemctl start pve-container@102' failed: exit code 1`.[image: This is the error]
When I execute the command `"systemctl status pve-container@102.service` this is what showed: [image: systemctl status]
And the command `journalctl -xe` showed: [image: journalctl -xe]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happened when you tried to check the filesystem yourself?

Comment: the command `pct fsck 102` returns `fsck from util-linux 2.29.2`
`/dev/mapper/pve-vm--102--disk--1: clean, 23291/262144 files, 183029/1048576 blocks`

Comment: That means it didn't actually check the filesystem. You'll have to force it.

Comment: How should to that?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/pct.1.html): `pct fsck 102 --force`

Comment: Nop, I execute that command and it does not start the container yet. Even i restarted the server

Answer (score 1):

Line 6 in your second debug-window says
    `EXT4-fs (dm-9): error loading journal`
Something is wrong with the EXT4 file-system in your container.

Try to fsck it!

Note1: Make sure the container image is not mounted before running fsck.
Note2: In case the fs contain important data, backup the image file before you proceed.

Try to fix the journal:
    `e2fsck -E journal_only /path/to/your/container_image.raw`

...or do a regular fsck on the whole ext4 fs:
    `e2fsck /path/to/your/container_image.raw`

If faults are found, and fsck think it can fix them, answer yes to the suggested fixes. Hopefully the container can now start up.

Comment: I have two virtual disk, the first is for the OS and the second to store the data. I unmount the second disk and the container start perfectly, but when I mount the second disk, returned that error