# Ubuntu 20.04 container failing to startup in Proxmox

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox, journalctl, ubuntu-20.04

Hello I have created a Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 container in Proxmox and both return the same error when I try to start them up after creating the container via the Proxmox GUI.

They fail to start and return the following error message:

```
Job for pve-container@100.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status pve-container@100.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
TASK ERROR: command 'systemctl start pve-container@100' failed: exit code 1
```

I found another serverfault question that sounds similar][1](https://serverfault.com/questions/939681/task-error-command-systemctl-start-pve-container102-failed-exit-code-1), however the error is slightly different and I have not even got to the step of being able to set anything up. These are clean Ubuntu templates downloaded right through Proxmox's official location. Also when I setup Proxmox I and the containers I left everything default including all the storage things.

I am a bit unclear on where to go from here or what to do.

I also did the `journalctl -xe` command and the `systemctl status` commands as the error messages indicates for details and here are the results:

```
# journalctl -xe
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit pve-container@100.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Killing process 14587 (lxc-start) with signal SIGKILL.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Killing process 14648 (apparmor_parser) with signal SIGKILL.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit pve-container@100.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: Failed to start PVE LXC Container: 100.
-- Subject: A start job for unit pve-container@100.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit pve-container@100.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 173480 and the job result is failed.
May 06 17:54:00 ns500282 systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
-- Subject: A start job for unit pvesr.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit pvesr.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 173490.
May 06 17:54:00 ns500282 systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The unit pvesr.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
May 06 17:54:00 ns500282 systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
-- Subject: A start job for unit pvesr.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit pvesr.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 173490.
```

and

```
# systemctl status pve-container@100.service
● pve-container@100.service - PVE LXC Container: 100
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pve-container@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-05-06 17:53:56 EDT; 2min 19s ago
     Docs: man:lxc-start
           man:lxc
           man:pct
  Process: 14579 ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-start -n 100 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 06 17:53:54 ns500282 systemd[1]: Starting PVE LXC Container: 100...
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 lxc-start[14579]: lxc-start: 100: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 874 Received container state "ABORTING" instead of "RUNNING"
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 lxc-start[14579]: lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 329 The container failed to start
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 lxc-start[14579]: lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 332 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 lxc-start[14579]: lxc-start: 100: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 335 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority 
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Killing process 14587 (lxc-start) with signal SIGKILL.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Killing process 14648 (apparmor_parser) with signal SIGKILL.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: pve-container@100.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 06 17:53:56 ns500282 systemd[1]: Failed to start PVE LXC Container: 100.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the same as the next :
https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/2754

There ssems to be a two solution.
solution 1. Use `PIDFile=`

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/lxc-%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-start -d -p /run/lxc-%i.pid -n %i
...
```

solution 2. Change the type from "forking" to "oneshot"

```
-Type=forking
+Type=oneshot
+RemainAfterExit=yes
```